# Difference in concatenated string length when using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, string

Just to test some code I wrote the following program in C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = "hello ";
    char *b = "there";
    char *c = malloc(100);
    strcat(c, a); 
    strcat(c, b); 
    printf("length of a is %d\n", strlen(a));
    printf("length of concatenated string is %d\n", strlen(c));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
length of a is 6
length of concatenated string is 11
```

Now instead of doing malloc, I did the following (rest of the code being the same):

```
char c[100];
```

The output changes to:

```
length of a is 6
length of concatenated string is 12
```

I don't understand why using a pointer over a char array would change the size of the concatenated string.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not put anything into `c` after calling `malloc`, the call of `strcat` leads to undefined behavior, because the allocated memory block may not contain the null terminator at all. In this case, `strcat` would eventually access memory beyond the allocated block during its search for a terminator.

This should make the calls consistent:

```
char *c = malloc(100);
*c = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

Behaviour in both examples is undefined.  [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) appends data after a terminating nul in the source string.  `c` is uninitialised so it is undefined where (and if) it'll have a nul terminator.

You'd get consistent results if you changed to use `strcpy` followed by `strcat`

```
strcpy(c, a); 
strcat(c, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use calloc to initialize elements of c to 0. Otherwise it remains unitialized before the first call of strcat and the result is undefined. Using an uninitialized variable like you do invokes undefined behavior and this is never good.